# AzureCLI get expired Vault Secrets

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, jmespath

Is there a way to list all expired secrets from an Azure Key Vault using the CLI?
So far I have

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name <MyVault> --output table --query [*].'{"Id":id,"expires":attributes.expires}'
```

This shows me a list

| Id | expires |

|Key1 | 2022-07-08 1200|

|Key2 | 2022-01-01 1200|

I want to be able to set a condition on attributes.expires like
attributes.expires < GetDate()

And therefore only return Key2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find full documentation here:

- [How to query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?tabs=concepts%2Cpowershell)

Here is a PowerShell sample to query all expired secrets:

```powershell
$vaultName = "<vault-name>"
$today = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

az keyvault secret list `
  --vault-name $vaultName `
  --query "[?attributes.expires <= '$today'].{Id:id, expires:attributes.expires}"
```